URLs in email being modified/mangled somehow
I'm sending (plain text) emails containing urls to a web site. They look like:

https://www.example.com/account/confirm/?place_id=ChIJA5Vy7Qfp2UcRpbHr9bNg4Tw

(The place_id parameter is a Place ID from the Google Maps API)

But my server logs show entries like

GET /account/confirm/?place_id=DuVWjMw28Eld43dEZhEcXEDcJfd

This only happens sometimes, I have plenty of entries that look as expected:

GET /account/confirm/?place_id=ChIJA5Vy7Qfp2UcRpbHr9bNg4Tw

And if I send test emails to myself, I get the correct URLs

Does anyone know what might be happening: how are these parameters getting mangled?. I'm using the following ruby code, running on AWS Lambda. The code connects via SMTP to a Gmail account:
require 'json'
require 'mail'
require 'securerandom'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  eventBody = JSON.parse(event["body"])

  smtp = eventBody['smtp']
  Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, {
        address: smtp['address'],
        port: smtp['port'],
        user_name: smtp['username'],
        password: smtp['password'],
        authentication: smtp['authentication'],
        enable_starttls_auto: smtp['enable_starttls_auto']
      }
  end

  mailConfig = eventBody['mail']
  mail = Mail.new do
    message_id      "<#{SecureRandom.uuid.upcase}@#{mailConfig['from']['address'].split('@').last}>"
    to              mailConfig['to']
    from            "#{mailConfig['from']['name']} <#{mailConfig['from']['address']}>"
    subject         mailConfig['subject']

    unless mailConfig['body'].nil?
      body          mailConfig['body']
    end
  end

  unless mailConfig['body_text'].nil?
    mail.text_part = Mail::Part.new do
      body          mailConfig['body_text']
    end
  end

  unless mailConfig['body_html'].nil?
    mail.html_part = Mail::Part.new do
      content_type  'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      body          mailConfig['body_html']
    end
  end

  unless mailConfig['headers'].nil?
    mailConfig['headers'].each do |name, value|
      mail.header[name] = value
    end
  end

  {
    statusCode: 201,
    body: JSON.generate({
      # event: event,
      # body: eventBody,
      # context: context,
      mail: mail.to_s
    })
}


It's just that being changed though - there's not much traffic so I've been over the logs. I think there's some sort of mapping going on - they're the same length, and almost always start with 'D' while the valid ids always start with 'C'

Would you mind explaining how the code you posted is related to the problem you are describing? What does an example email look like? What do you mean by you are sending to a website? I am asking because that is technically not possible. So how do the emails look like? How are the emails connected to the website? What does the application receiving the email look like?

Sorry, I was slightly ambiguous in my phrasing. I'm sending emails which contain URLs (the URLs point to a web site, the emails are being sent to various email addresses). The code is an AWS Lambda function that receives the details of the email to be sent (smtp credentials, recipient, subject, body, etc) and uses the ruby mail gem to send the email

Are you logging the mails you send also? How can you be sure it's not your system sending the incorrect links in the first place?

I include my own address as a test when I send the emails. When I receive them, the links are correct. Furthermore, the logs show plenty of entries with the correct place_id parameter.

@SteveK did you check all outgoing emails? Were they all correct? If so, the problem doesn't seem to be on your side. Maybe someone just tries to put in random values?

@Stefan, yes I've checked the sent folder (it's a Gmail account). All URLs are correct
